# How can I do a threaded Client socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I've done a simple ASPX page with just one `<asp:Button>`. This page will do a connection with a Windows Form application via Socket.

**How Should Work**

Everytime that I click in my `<asp:Button>` I have to pass some information to my Windows Form read, and then I will print it.

**TCP Server Code**

```
public partial class PaginaTeste : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnBotao_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8849);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        this.listenThread.Start();
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //create a thread to handle communication 
            //with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                string serverResponse = "571764;10.";                        
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                clientStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                clientStream.Flush();
            }
            catch
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                break;
            }
        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
```

**Client Code (Windows Form)**

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpClient clientsocket2;
        Thread thread;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
        }

        private void button3_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.clientsocket2 = new TcpClient();
           clientsocket2.Connect("server_ip", 8849);       
            this.thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.imprimir));
            this.thread.Start();
        }
protected void imprimir()
        {       
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientsocket2.GetStream();
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientsocket2.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);

            string r = "Printing Test";
            int retorno = -1;

            retorno = IniciaPorta("COM7");            

            if (retorno == 1)
            {
                ConfiguraModeloImpressora(7);
                BematechTX(r);
                AcionaGuilhotina(1);
                FechaPorta();
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
        }
```

**Problem**

If I click once in my `<asp:Button>` and initiallize my `Client Application` works fine. In the second time that I click in my `<asp:Button>` the parameter that I pass to my `Client Application` return empty.

**Where I read empty in my client application**

`string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);`

Comment: Running a `TcpListener` (which is a *server*) as part of a page (which represents part of a request) is raising some real red flags for me... what is it you're trying to do here?

Comment: Open communication in a specific port in my server. I have a printer, and the I've done a Windows Application where I access this printer via DLL. In my Web Application, I will send data, to print in this printer. So my Web Application will send data to Windows Form and windows form send to printer. I've tryied do the communcation with `ActiveX` but our web application will just run in FireFox.

Comment: Why doesn't the winform just consume something like a REST API / web-service?

Comment: Do you have some example to show me how can I do this ?

Comment: just search for "web service ASP.NET"

Comment: This is such a good idea, but I will need save this information in a database ?

Comment: That is an entirely separate question, that would be researchable via ".NET use a database"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you create tcpListener when press button in your page?
You need create TcpClient and send comand to you Winform App
This code send comand and get reply from server

```
string data = "Some_Comand";
        byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        var client = new TcpClient();
        var serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("ip"), 8010);
        client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
        var clientStream = client.GetStream();
        clientStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        Socket s = client.Client;
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[200];
        s.Receive(receiveData);
        Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveData));
```

Thats all

Comment: there's a lot of `IDisposable` objects there that should be in a `using` statement